# Image over image, middle position

Tags: html, css, image, position

This is my CSS class:

```
.overitem {
    position: relative; 
    background: url(images/bg.png) no-repeat; 
    width:83px;
    height: 83px;
}

.sit {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 50%; 
    left: 50%;
}
```

My HTML :

```
<div class="overitem"><img src="/images/vcs.png" class="sit"/></div>
```

The problem is that I can not make the from the `img` tag, in a middle of the background of `overitem` class. What should I do, to make it appear in the middle of the `bg.png` image?

Comment: what is the dimensions of `vcs.png`?

Comment: vcs.png is an example because its placed in the `foreach` and then I do select another image for each loop - in the results, there are hundreds of images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `.sit` class has to have a fixed width and height (because its an image), you can use the following method:

```
    .sit {
       position: absolute;
       top: 50%;
       left: 50%;
       width: 500px;
       height: 500px;
       margin-top: -250px; /* Half the height */
       margin-left: -250px; /* Half the width */
    }
```

Source: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/absolute-center-vertical-horizontal-an-image/

Answer (score 2):

you can set margins as
    1/2(width of "overitem" minus width of "sit") and
    1/2(height of "overitem" height width of "sit")
or try this:

```
.sit {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -(HALF_OF_WIDTH_OF_IMAGE);
    margin-top: -(HALF_OF_HEIGHT_OF_IMAGE);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
elems = document.getElementsByClassName('sit');
for( i = 0, j = elems.length; i < j; i++){
    elems[ i ].style.marginLeft = ( elems[ i ].parentNode.offsetWidth - elems[ i ].offsetWidth ) / 2;
    elems[ i ].style.marginTop = ( elems[ i ].parentNode.offsetHeight - elems[ i ].offsetHeight ) / 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the .sit class you need to have:

```
margin-left: -(half of width);
margin-top: -(half of height);
```

An alternative option is:

```
.overitem { 
    position: relative;  
    background: url(images/bg.png) no-repeat;  
    width:83px; 
    height: 83px; 
    line-height: 83px;
} 

.sit { 
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: div does not have `vertical-align`... Use `<div align="center"...` instead.

Comment: .sit is not a div, its an image, that aligns within the line-height.